# insert some data after response on node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I wrote a website tracker for internal use, since Google Analytic don't meet the requirement.

I use node.js with Express to develop that tracking system. Everything works well so far. But I want to confirm is, if there is some problem behind if I insert a log data after response a image.

Thanks!

```
function image_response(req, res, next){
    var buf = new Buffer([0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38, 0x39, 0x61, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x2c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x02, 0x44, 0x01, 0x00, 0x3b]);
    res.send(200, buf);
    next();
}

app.get('/tracker.gif', image_response, function(req, res){
     // blah blah blah 
     // DB insert codes..
}
```

Actually the "image_response" is completely end of the response and close the browser connection with client. Afterward, doing the logic to save the data to DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant modify the result if you did `res.send()`, use `res.write()` + `res.end()` instead.

`res.send()` is a convenience method of express which unites res.write() and res.end() for easy use. If you want to send data in the response in multiple places you have to use the nodejs' methods write and end on the result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually the "image_response" is completely end of the response. What I want is closing the browser connection its send the image to client. afterward, doing the logic to save the data to DB.

Comment: the middleware works in and out, if you add some code after `next()` the code is executed on the way out.

Comment: Thank you again. so, as my above codes, is the connection between browser & client end in the middleware? the db insert codes is work "behind" after closed the connection?

Comment: yes your middleware closes the connection and sends the buffer to the client. Usually this is only used to abort the connection in case of a problem for example (called provider as a representative of the application). Your application logic should be behind the middleware.

Comment: Thanks! I am clear now. one more question is, am i wrong using middleware in this case?

Comment: For tracking purposes a middleware is the right decision. If you do place the tracking middleware in front of your application and do some logic on the request or on the response this will work. But you have to do the logic in the middleware not in the application itself as above (bg Logic in the application). Do the DB Logic in the middleware and serve the image in the application.

Comment: yeah, your suggesting is exactly what I thought if I needed to do some logic on request in the further. Thank you so much!